# Artifactory Nuget Restore Failing

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I've setup a Nuget Remote Repository that points to official [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) site.
It was able to download all the packages, but at the end of the log it is throwing an error.

```
[Error] File ILMerge.2.13.0307 doesn't exists
```

This is really weird because I can see that the artifact was downloaded. It's existing in my hard drive.

One thing I noticed though is the casing differences:

- Package name in the repository: **ilmerge.2.13.0307.nupkg**
- Package name in my hard drive: ILMerge.2.13.0307.nupkg
- Package name in package.json file: ILMerge

I suspect that artifactory compares the package name. I maybe wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily solved the issue by disabling the `Collect Build Info` settings in Artifactory Nuget Task. **But this isn't the permanent solution.**

See image below:

[image: Artifactory Task]